# How do I change the format of a date in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and programming in general. I'm trying to write a program that will convert a date from the format "mm/dd/yyyy" to (for example) : "Your date is January 12, 2019".

I tried this code but it gives me 'None' for the month key. I don't know how to fix it. Please help!

```
date = input('Enter your date in the format mm/dd/yyyy: ')
date_list = list(date.split('/'))
monthConvert = {
    '01': 'January',
    '02': 'February',
    '03': 'March',
    '04': 'April',
    '05': 'May',
    '06': 'June',
    '07': 'July',
    '08': 'August',
    '09': 'September',
    '10': 'October',
    '11': 'November',
    '12': 'December',
}


def month():
    if '01' in date_list[0]:
        print(monthConvert['01'])
    elif '02' in date_list[0]:
        print(monthConvert['02'])
    elif '03' in date_list[0]:
        print(monthConvert['03'])
    elif '04' in date_list[0]:
        print(monthConvert['04'])
    elif '05' in date_list[0]:
        print(monthConvert['05'])
    elif '06' in date_list[0]:
        print(monthConvert['06'])
    elif '07' in date_list[0]:
        print(monthConvert['07'])
    elif '08' in date_list[0]:
        print(monthConvert['08'])
    elif '09' in date_list[0]:
        print(monthConvert['09'])
    elif '10' in date_list[0]:
        print(monthConvert['10'])
    elif '11' in date_list[0]:
        print(monthConvert['11'])
    elif '12' in date_list[0]:
        print(monthConvert['12'])


print('\nYour date is the', date_list[1], 'of ', month(), ',',  date_list[2])
```

Comment: You want your month() function to return the value instead of printing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be converted easily using `datetime` module as below

```
from datetime import datetime
date = '11/24/2019'
new_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%B %d, %Y')
print(new_date)
```

This will give you the below output

```
November 24, 2019
```

Here you can find more details about datetime format. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 4):

The [answer by Prince Francis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59337657/339424) provides the best (i.e. "most Pythonic") was to convert the date as you would like. However, the issue with your function as provided is that your Month() function is not returning a value. Each of your "if/elif" conditions prints a value rather than returning that value, so when you call Month(...) the function returns None, which is the default return value for any Python function that does not have a `return` statement.

Also, it should be mentioned that your conditions should probably use `==` instead of `in`. While `in` will work, it may provide unexpected results if the string `1001` is provided (for instance), as it searches within the string rather than testing for equivalence.